# Rstudio viewer pane is not working, for plotly and leaflet visualizations?

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

I'm using latest version of rstudio, I wrote this code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
data("BOD")
head(BOD)
ggplotly(ggplot(BOD, aes(x = Time, y = demand)) + 
           geom_point())
```

and my rstudio viewer tab showed this not any plotly graph!!!!

```
/session/viewhtml17e429a6510a/index.html?viewer_pane=1&capabilities=1&host=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A12450 not found
```

I searched about it everywhere but did not got anything, I'll be so thankful if you can help me in that.

Comment: Can you try the patched update for rstudio

Comment: Please specify the version of Rstudio and R.  I tried on `1.4.1106` and it is working fine

Comment: I am using Rstudio Version 1.4.1717.

Comment: thanks,  there was some issue with Rstudio and ggplot using R 4.1.0.  Try the preview version or patched one

Comment: what's the patched update? Thanks for answering akrun!

Comment: You may check the [issue](https://community.rstudio.com/t/ggplot2-crashes-in-rstudio-but-work-is-base-r/105616) and probably the preview version is `RStudio v1.4.1714-2`

Comment: Ekrun, it's same error after installing preview version,  it's RStudio v1.4.1722-2.

Comment: How can I install older Version of rstudio? 1.4.1106

Comment: I have installed version 1.4.1103 but it's not working 

Comment: Try the preview version `v1.4.1714-2`

Comment: I installed R version R-4.1 and latest Rstudio version, now its working fine. THANK YOU!!

Comment: Greattoknowthatitworks!